# ggploting multiple graphs from a data list

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I would like to do something along the lines of this post: [R: saving ggplot2 plots in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357139/r-saving-ggplot2-plots-in-a-list)
The problem is I can't get it to work. I seem to be able to get the individual graphs but the `facet_wrap` throws out an error. I would be content with just outputting all the graphs and then saving them to disk as a jpg or something, so I can scroll through them later.

```
for(n in 1:5){
  pdata <- data.frame(mt1[n])
  library(ggplot2)
  p <-ggplot(pdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Legend, group=Legend))+ geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~ color)

}
```

Link to a `dput` of the data : [mt1](http://sdrv.ms/XyWigN)

Edit:
Added the whole correct file, its a bit long

Comment: mt1 is a mess (see `names(mt1)`), did you obtain it from some other data.frame?

Comment: also, the title and your for loop suggest that you think mt1 should be a list of data.frames, right? (it is not)

Comment: yes, I see what you mean. The `dput` and `dget` import export messed the thing up a bit. It should be a variable `list[5]`.

Comment: that's a different issue; for this question, try posting here some mock-up data with the structure you think the data should have

Comment: I see what went wrong. I was trying to cut the file down with `head(mt1, n = 10L)` but since its a list it didn't want to cut it so I first converted it to a `data.frame`

Comment: Not that it matters too much but why do you have the library call _inside_ the for loop?

Comment: thats a direct result of copy paste, probably not the best thing as it will get called 5 times.

Comment: added the new data file

Comment: You are trying to facet your graphs with a `color` variable, but there is no such variable in your data frames...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we omit the `facet` error due to a missing variable in your data frames, you can generate and save your plots in different files this way using `ggsave` :

```
for(n in 1:5){
  pdata <- data.frame(mt1[n]) # better to use mt1[[n]]
  p <-ggplot(pdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Legend, group=Legend))+ geom_line()
  ggsave(paste0("plot",n,".jpg"), p)
}
```

**Some suggestions for improvement:**

First, as @Dason points out, your `library(ggplot2)` call should be outside your loop.

Second, if you access an element of list by `[.]`, then the result will still be a list. You should do instead: `[[.]]` which will render the `data.frame(.)` call unnecessary (as commented above in the code).

Third is a suggestion to use `*apply` family of functions. Here, using `lapply`.

To summarise all these points in code:

```
require(ggplot2) # load package outside once
o <- lapply(seq_along(mtl), function(idx) {
    p <- ggplot(mtl[[idx]], aes(x = variable, y = value, 
              color = Legend, group = Legend))+ geom_line()
    ggsave(paste0("plot",idx,".jpg"), p)
})
```

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect some improvements/suggestions, instead of writing a redundant answer (that'll be half-and-half). Hope you don't mind.