# Creating a list of ggplots in a loop, using the index of the loop as an argument to the geom function

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

This loop creates a list of 3 ggplots, but because the arguments for `x` and `xend` depend on the index of the loop, dismay follows:

```
DF <- data.frame(column1=c(1,2,3,4,5), column2=c(4,5,6,7,8))

list_of_ggplots <- list()

for (num in seq(1:3)){ 
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF, aes(x=column1[num], xend=column2[num], y=1, yend=1))

  list_of_ggplots[[num]] <- p }
list_of_ggplots
```

We get 3 plots being fundamentally the same plot (since at the point in time they are called, `num` is 3).

What could be a better strategy to create these plots?

Comment: Do you want make this without a loop?

Comment: The loop structure could be changed / altered / removed, as long as it basically does the same thing...dynamically creating a variable number of plots where the index for accessing the data in the dataframe is given based on the iteration over seq(1:n).  Or something equivalent to seq(1:n).

Comment: this could help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357139/r-saving-ggplot2-plots-in-a-list)

Comment: Just subset the data set outside of `aes`: `geom_segment(data=DF[num,], aes(x=column1, xend=column2, y=1, yend=1))`

Comment: replace `aes` by `aes_q` and pass the values directly: `aes_q(x=DF$column1[num], xend=DF$column2[num], y=1, yend=1)`

Comment: Can someone please explain what is going on underneath this tiny, seemingly cosmetic change in the code? I never would have figured this out..

Comment: `aes` creates a list of **unevaluated** expressions, which are evaluated when you're attempting to generate plots--that is why `num` is the same in all plots in your example. One way to avoid the problem of late evaluation of `num` is to put it outside of `aes`, so I suggested to directly subset DF. Another approach, suggested by @kohske, is to use a variation of the `aes` function, called `aes_q`, which evaluates everything in place.

Comment: Why was it implemented like this; are there any advantages? Does it play any particular role or service in the course of creating visualizations?

Comment: The problem statement in your post is "We get 3 plots being fundamentally the same" and in the duplicate it's "my problem is that each graph that is plotted uses data from the same column". Both times the issue is that looping over columns to create `ggplot` objects does not work. How are these not the same problems?

Comment: His/her problem revolves needing to display multiple plots on the same page. My problem revolves around at what time expressions in ggplot are evaluated. There are some similarities, but at the very least the solutions are absolutely different. Facet wrapping and layout issues play no role in the solution to my question nor were they the problem, nor would they solve my problem. Regardless, "This question already has an answer here:" is simply not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list without running explicit loops by using `lapply`:

```
list_of_ggplots <- lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i) {ggplot(DF[i,]) + aes(x=column1, xend=column2, y=1, yend=1)+geom_segment()})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the list in a more "R"-like way with `lapply` and then just subset `DF` with `num` vs trying to do so in the aesthetics. However, you should also use `scale_x_continuous` and set the `limits`, otherwise they'll all still "look" the same (except for the #'s on the x axis)

```
list_of_ggplots <- lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(num) {
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF[num,], aes(x=column1, xend=column2, y=1, yend=1))
  p + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(DF$column2))) 
})
```