# list of ggplots repeating one plot when using lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have not had much experience with `lapply` so I was hoping someone could help me here. 
I saw the suggestion of using lapply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596979/creating-a-list-of-ggplots-in-a-loop-using-the-index-of-the-loop-as-an-argument). 
My data is in columns and I have created a vector to separate samples into two groups. This is a very simplified version, I would expect a single point to be plotted for G1 and 2 points for G0.

```
>DF
      V1 V2 V3
    S1 3  5  6
    S2 2  7  2
    S3 4  5  7


status = c("G0","G0", "G1")
```

My simplified code to plot one plot is

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=status, y=DF[,1])) +geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))
```

When I use `lapply` to create a list of plots, it just does the same plot repeated.

```
list_of_plots<-lapply(1:3,function(i) {ggplot(DF, aes(x=status, y=DF[,i])) +geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))})
```

Any ideas why? or any other ideas in a way to create a list of ggplots?
I want to use multiplot function to plot multiple of these plots to a pdf.

Here is an example from my real data[image]

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. Please provide data that will run with your code. For example, where is `status`? Also, you reference columns 4 through 6, but your data has only 3 columns.

Comment: This works for me (taking `status` as being `1:2` and if I replace `4:6` with `1:3`).

Comment: I know. But I think it's reasonable to expect people to provide a working reproducible example, rather than expect others to take the time to do it.

Comment: Absolutely @ eipi10. I have edited to change 4:6 to 1:3 and a status list.

Comment: Now I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Are you saying that `status` = "G0" for both values of `V1`? That would mean there would be only one x-value to plot and there would be two points plotted above that x value. Is that what you're trying to do? Can you post an image of your first plot?

Comment: You're absolutely right @eipi10, I was just trying to say that I couldn't reproduce the problem. Now it seems `status` is the problem.. The updated example is not reproducible, `status` is of length 3, `DF[, i]` of length 2.

Comment: Sorry again @eipi10, I have put a real example from my data. For the data I have given you, there would be one point  above G1 and two points above G0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your data actually looks like, because `status` in your example data is different from `status` in the plot you posted. In any case, here's an example of how to create a separate plot for each column of data:

```
library(gridExtra) # For grid.arrange function

# Data frame based on your sample data
DF = structure(list(status = c("S1", "S2"), V1 = c(3L, 2L), V2 = c(5L,7L), V3 = c(6L, 2L)), .Names = c("status", "V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

DF
  status V1 V2 V3
1     S1  3  5  6
2     S2  2  7  2

list_of_plots<-lapply(names(DF)[2:4], function(i) {
  ggplot(DF, aes_string(x="status", y=i)) +
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, are the point not being incorrectly plotted. For example with V1 the S1 should be plotted on 3 not above 3?

Comment: You've jittered the points, so they'll be plotted in some random location near their actual values.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Sorry about the vague-ness of my questioning. Status for my data isn't S1 (these would be sample names). However your answers is perfect and I can easily apply this to my data!